# Vertical scroll bar is moving top when I open light-box

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

I have big page with row by row data.
Each data contains link on which light-box will get open.

On clicking on link light-box is opening but my scroll bar is moving top and after closing light-box scroll bar will remain at top. When I use button instead of link then working fine.

Here is code.

CSS:

```
#reportSpamFade {

    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index:1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity:.80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);

}

#reportSpamLight {

    display  : none;
    position : fixed;
    top      : 37%;
    left     : 33.80%;
    width    : 1000px;
    height   : 555px;
    margin   : -190px 0 0 -281px;
    z-index  : 1002;
    overflow : hidden;
    background-color: white;

}
```

javascript:

```
function reportSpam_open(){
    document.getElementById('reportSpamLight').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('reportSpamFade').style.display='block';    
}
function reportSpam_close(){
    document.getElementById('reportSpamLight').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('reportSpamFade').style.display='none';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write hidden overflow to body. Here is code:

```
function reportSpam_open(){
    document.getElementById('reportSpamLight').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('reportSpamFade').style.display='block';
    document.body.style.overflow='hidden';
}
function reportSpam_close(){
    document.getElementById('reportSpamLight').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('reportSpamFade').style.display='none';
    document.body.style.overflow='visible';
}
```

Comment: No I tried this early but still no use. After making it visible scroll bar is going to top again.

Comment: Is there any way to locate scroll bar position.

Comment: When I use button instead of link then working fine. I have updated the same in OP.